# View is missing one or more required columns

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, view

I have a list with a lookup column and a people picker column. The form works great. When I try and paste multiple records in the Quick Edit screen I get the error "Sorry, you can't create a new item with Quick Edit because this view is missing one or more required columns. To create a new item, please click New Item or add required columns to this view".

The only two columns I have are there. Interestingly, the people picker column doesn't appear to be resolving names. So I'm guessing that is the culprit. Any ideas?

Comment: 2010, 2013, or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually OOTB, Title is a required field. I would add all the columns possible in order to have Datasheet view work correctly. Also, if your column is indeed there, there needs to be something in the field in order for the datasheet view to commit your changes, or else you get that message popup,

> "Sorry, you can't create a new item with Quick Edit because this view
>   is missing one or more required columns. To create a new item, please
>   click New Item or add required columns to this view".

Check the data that you are pasting and see if they all have data fields present and is in the correct format.

Alternatively, you can edit the list/library fields to be optional.

Comment: Bingo! Even though title isn't required, I still had to add it to the view. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pasting in the names using DOMAIN\Username format?

Comment: The users are FBA

Answer (score 0):

On ours, you have to use the user's email address instead of the name.

But back to the other problem... all my task lists are the same way.  I can't save a record in quick edit mode unless I add the "Name" field to view and enter something in it too.  The problem is that the name field is not something I added.  It's some kind of Sharpoint BS.  It's basically an ID, but it needs a value to save the record and for some reason it can't create that value itself.  Very frustrating....